# Python :How to set focus on dynamic TextInput

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy`.
When i run `test.py` then screen looks like attached image. When i click on `+Add More` button then row will be add `dynamic`. If i fill value like attached image after click on `Ok` button then i can find blank value `TextInput` using this code.

```
        a = 1
        for val in values:
            print(val)
            if val[1] == "":
                print("row"+str(a) +" TextInput 1 is required")
                break;

            if val[2] == "":
                print("row"+str(a) +" TextInput 2 is required")
                break;
            a = a+1
```

But can someone tell me how to set focus into first blank `TextInput` like attached image.

[image]

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Window.size = (450, 525)


class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()

    def insert(self):

        values = []
        rows = self.ids.rows

        for row in reversed(rows.children):
            vals = []
            for ch in reversed(row.children):
                if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                    vals.append(ch.text)
                if isinstance(ch, Button):
                    vals.insert(0, ch.text)
            values.append(vals)

        a = 1
        for val in values:
            print(val)
            if val[1] == "":
                print("row"+str(a) +" TextInput 1 is required")
                break;

            if val[2] == "":
                print("row"+str(a) +" TextInput 2 is required")
                break;
            a = a+1


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")

    def count_row(self):
        print('count row')


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Row>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 0, 5

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2

    TextInput:
        size_hint_x: .4

    TextInput:
        size_hint_x: .4
display:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "SN"
                valign: 'bottom'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "Value1"
                valign: 'bottom'
            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "Value2"
                valign: 'bottom'

        Rows:
            id: rows


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 0
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .7
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.insert()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ignore first column (value1) of every row for blank value

1. In the kv file, remove the children *TextInput* widgets from the class *Row*.
2. In the Python script, when instantiate the first *TextInput* widget, provide an *id='value1'*.

Please refer to the snippets below for details.

### Snippets

#### main.py

```
class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()

    def insert(self):

        rows = self.ids.rows

        for row in reversed(rows.children):
            for ch in reversed(row.children):
                if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                    if ch.text == "" and ch.id != 'value1':
                        print("\nch.id=", ch.id)
                        print("TextInput is required")
                        ch.focus = True
                        break;


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(TextInput(id="value1", size_hint_x=0.4))
        self.add_widget(TextInput(size_hint_x=0.4))
```

#### test.kv

```
<Row>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 0, 5

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2
```

## Check TextInput of every row for blank value

The solution is as follow:

### Snippets

```
class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()

    def insert(self):

        rows = self.ids.rows

        for row in reversed(rows.children):
            for ch in reversed(row.children):
                if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                    if ch.text == "":
                        print("TextInput is required")
                        ch.focus = True
                        break;
```

## Output - Ignore first column (value1) of every row for blank value

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

## Output - Check TextInput of every row for blank value

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

Comment: thanks. Can i ignore first column (value1) of every row for blank value like this add condition `if ch.text == "" and ch.id ='value1' :`

Comment: @Martin; Please refer to my updated my post to include ignore first column (value1) of every row for blank value.